# How to add curve path to connect flow widgets from two columns in qt?

Tags: qt

I know this question is somehow hard to describe, so a picture may help, as following:
[image: picture states curve connects two widgets from different two column]

I'm developing application in qt-5.15.x. Say I have a window or widget or something else which can layout two columns of widgets(customized, call it `rectangle` here), I want to:

1. drag and drop one item up or down within same column by mouse
2. connect two widgets from two different columns with a customized curve path by mouse
3. all elements(rectangle and curve item) have mouse events: move, hover, click and key event
4. the contents of window or widget can scroll vertically due to more and more items will be added

Before this, I have implemented bazier curve, graphicsview with customized widgets and connecting these widgets with bazier curve, but all these widgets don't lay on line(horizontally or vertically).
So my question is not about how to implement it in detail, but just a guide - what widget , layout or event something else in qt I can use, or which document I can refer to. I have searched a lot, but with no results.

Answer (score 0):

OPs requirement can be achieved by simply deriving a widget from `QWidget` and overriding the `paintEvent()`.

Beside of that, the derived widget still can contain children and layout managers, so that both can be combined.

Sample code `testQWidgetPaintOverChildren.cc` to demonstrate:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Canvas: public QWidget {

  private:
    using Link = std::pair<int, int>;

    std::vector<Link> _links;

  public:
    void addLink(int from, int to)
    {
      _links.emplace_back(from, to);
      update();
    }

  protected:
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent) override;

};

void Canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent)
{
  QWidget::paintEvent(pQEvent);
  const int lenTan = 64;
  QPainter qPainter(this);
  auto drawCurve = [&](const QPoint& qPosFrom, const QPoint& qPosTo) {
    QPainterPath qPath;
    qPath.moveTo(qPosFrom);
    qPath.cubicTo(qPosFrom + QPoint(lenTan, 0), qPosTo - QPoint(lenTan, 0), qPosTo);
    qPainter.drawPath(qPath);
  };
  const QObjectList& pQChildren = children();
  for (const Link& link : _links) {
    const int from = link.first;
    if (from >= pQChildren.size()) continue; // invalid from index
    const QWidget* pQWidgetFrom
      = dynamic_cast<const QWidget*>(pQChildren[from]);
    if (!pQWidgetFrom) continue; // shouldn't happen
    const int to = link.second;
    if (to >= pQChildren.size()) continue; // invalid to index
    const QWidget* pQWidgetTo
      = dynamic_cast<const QWidget*>(pQChildren[to]);
    if (!pQWidgetTo) continue; // shouldn't happen
    const QPoint qPosFrom
      = pQWidgetFrom->pos() + QPoint(3 * pQWidgetFrom->width() / 4, pQWidgetFrom->height() / 2);
    const QPoint qPosTo
      = pQWidgetTo->pos() + QPoint(1 * pQWidgetTo->width() / 4, pQWidgetTo->height() / 2);
    //qPainter.drawLine(qPosFrom, qPosTo);
    drawCurve(qPosFrom, qPosTo);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  Canvas qCanvas;
  qCanvas.setWindowTitle("Test Draw Over Children");
  qCanvas.resize(320, 240);
  QGridLayout qGrid;
  qGrid.setSpacing(16);
#define ITEM(ROW, COL) \
  QLabel qLbl##ROW##COL("txt "#ROW", "#COL); \
  qLbl##ROW##COL.setAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter); \
  qLbl##ROW##COL.setFrameStyle(QFrame::Box | QFrame::Plain); \
  qGrid.addWidget(&qLbl##ROW##COL, ROW - 1, COL - 1)
  ITEM(1, 1); ITEM(1, 2);
  ITEM(2, 1); ITEM(2, 2);
  ITEM(3, 1); ITEM(3, 2);
  ITEM(4, 1); ITEM(4, 2);
  qCanvas.setLayout(&qGrid);
  qCanvas.addLink(1, 8);
  qCanvas.addLink(5, 2);
  qCanvas.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.15.1
```

[image: Snapshot of testQWidgetPaintOverChildren]

---

The drawback of this first attempt is that the links are drawn *under* the children. In the case of the `QLabel`, this isn't visible as `QLabel`s are mostly transparent. Replacing them by `QPushButton`s makes this obvious.

This can be solved by using two widgets, one as container for children, the other for drawing the links, and ensuring that the second widget has the same position and size than the first.

Improved sample code `testQWidgetPaintOverChildren.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget: public QWidget {

  private:
    using Link = std::pair<int, int>;

    struct Canvas: public QWidget {
      std::vector<Link> links; 
    
      using QWidget::QWidget;

      virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent) override;
    } _canvas;
    
  public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget* pQParent = nullptr):
      QWidget(pQParent),
      _canvas(this)
    { }

  public:
    void addLink(int from, int to)
    {
      _canvas.links.emplace_back(from, to);
      _canvas.update();
      _canvas.setParent(nullptr);
      _canvas.setParent(this);
    }
  protected:
    virtual void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* pQEvent) override
    {
      QWidget::resizeEvent(pQEvent);
      _canvas.resize(size());
    }
};

void Widget::Canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent* pQEvent)
{
  QWidget::paintEvent(pQEvent);
  const int lenTan = 64;
  QPainter qPainter(this);
  auto drawCurve = [&](const QPoint& qPosFrom, const QPoint& qPosTo) {
    QPainterPath qPath;
    qPath.moveTo(qPosFrom);
    qPath.cubicTo(qPosFrom + QPoint(lenTan, 0), qPosTo - QPoint(lenTan, 0), qPosTo);
    qPainter.drawPath(qPath);
  };
  const QObjectList& pQChildren = parent()->children();
  for (const Link& link : links) {
    const int from = link.first;
    if (from >= pQChildren.size()) continue; // invalid from index
    const QWidget* pQWidgetFrom
      = dynamic_cast<const QWidget*>(pQChildren[from]);
    if (!pQWidgetFrom) continue; // shouldn't happen
    const int to = link.second;
    if (to >= pQChildren.size()) continue; // invalid to index
    const QWidget* pQWidgetTo
      = dynamic_cast<const QWidget*>(pQChildren[to]);
    if (!pQWidgetTo) continue; // shouldn't happen
    const QPoint qPosFrom
      = pQWidgetFrom->pos() + QPoint(3 * pQWidgetFrom->width() / 4, pQWidgetFrom->height() / 2);
    const QPoint qPosTo
      = pQWidgetTo->pos() + QPoint(1 * pQWidgetTo->width() / 4, pQWidgetTo->height() / 2);
    //qPainter.drawLine(qPosFrom, qPosTo);
    drawCurve(qPosFrom, qPosTo);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // setup GUI
  Widget qWinMain;
  qWinMain.setWindowTitle("Test Draw Over Children");
  qWinMain.resize(320, 240);
  QGridLayout qGrid;
  qGrid.setSpacing(16);
#define ITEM(ROW, COL) \
  QPushButton qBtn##ROW##COL("txt "#ROW", "#COL); \
  qGrid.addWidget(&qBtn##ROW##COL, ROW - 1, COL - 1)
  ITEM(1, 1); ITEM(1, 2);
  ITEM(2, 1); ITEM(2, 2);
  ITEM(3, 1); ITEM(3, 2);
  ITEM(4, 1); ITEM(4, 2);
#undef ITEM
  qWinMain.setLayout(&qGrid);
  qWinMain.addLink(1, 8);
  qWinMain.addLink(5, 2);
  qWinMain.show();
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
Qt Version: 5.15.1
```

[image: Snapshot of testQWidgetPaintOverChildren]

Comment: Oh, QWidget is really powerful, but I never come up with this way. Thanks, I will try it and be back soon. BTW, considering I have to implement almost all the mouse and key events in order to supporting mouse and key events, is there any other way to reach it with as little codes as possible?

Comment: @taptiptop To add interaction, you have to overload the resp. mouse events as well. Thereby, the `Widget::Canvas` will probably receive all events first, as it is painted last and covers the whole widget. With the appropriate `pQEvent->reject()`, it should be possible to let events "fall through" which didn't hit any link. Concerning key events, it depends on whether the children can be focused...

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing all this. But how about `drag and drop` - dragging and dropping item up or down onto the same column by mouse, pushing away other widgets in same column? Besides, by `is there any other way to reach it with as little codes as possible`, I mean other exist qt widgets or layout ways to solve my original question as title says.